# IntelliJ multiple carets - search from each caret

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

While having multiple carets, is it possible to search for a character, and each caret will jump to the location of that character relative to the caret position?

For example, in the screenshot below, how to do jump to the next comma (',') for each of the carets?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One awkward method which **sometimes** can do the job is:

1. Change to column selection
2. Select the area where all relevant search results appear
3. Apply "Replace..."
4. Ensure "In Selection" is checked
5. Type the search string
6. Click "Select All Occurrences"

Would be much nicer if Incremental Search would work with multi-carets.